# Transaccionalidad de un metodo con varios procedimientos almacenados

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo una clase en java que ejecuta varios procedimientos almacenados, ejecuta procedimientos independientes pero al momento de que alguno o el mismo software genera algún error, los datos de los procedimientos almacenados ejecutados quedan guardados, necesito que al ejecutarse el método y al encontrar algún error se realice un rollback a todos los procedimientos almacenados utilizados.

Adjunto el método que utilizo.

```
public ResponseEntity<Message> postSolicitud(@Valid @PathVariable String userName, @Valid @RequestBody Solicitud solicitud) throws Exception {

    Message m = new Message("");
    try {
        //List<DatosAfiliado> listAfiliado = this.usuarioInterface.datosAfiliado(solicitud.getNumDocumento(), solicitud.getTipoDocumento().getTipoDoc());
        List<DatosAfiliado> existenteAfiliado = new ArrayList<>();
        DatosAfiliado afiliado = new DatosAfiliado();
        if ("0".equals(solicitud.getNumContrato().trim())) {
            //Entra por no Afiliado, Indicando que el numero de contraro es 0, para este caso
            existenteAfiliado = this.usuarioInterface.validaExistente(solicitud.getNumDocumento(), solicitud.getTipoDocumento().getName());
            if (!existenteAfiliado.isEmpty()) {
                m.setTexto("Usuario existente, por favor validar documento y numero de contrato");
                return new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            } else {
                //creacion
                int idUserNoAfiliado = this.solicitudInterface.creacionNoAfiliado(solicitud);
                if (idUserNoAfiliado == 1) {

                    afiliado.setIndicador("-123");
                    existenteAfiliado.add(afiliado);

                } else {
                    m.setTexto("Error al crear usuario no afiliado");
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                }
            }
        } else {
            existenteAfiliado = this.usuarioInterface.validaExistenteAfiliado(solicitud.getNumDocumento(), solicitud.getNumContrato(), solicitud.getTipoDocumento().getId());
            if (existenteAfiliado.isEmpty()) {
                m.setTexto("Usuario con contrato " + solicitud.getNumContrato() + " no encontrado");
                return new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }

        solicitud.setFechaHoraEchos(Timestamp.from(Instant.now()));

        String nombreUser = this.solicitudInterface.getFullName(userName);
        //solicitud.setNumDocumento(solicitud.getNumDocumento());
        int envioSolicitud = this.solicitudInterface.preRadicacion(solicitud, userName, nombreUser);

        if (envioSolicitud > 0) {
            Solicitud.setIdTicket(Integer.toString(envioSolicitud));
            if (existenteAfiliado.get(0).getIndicador() != null) {
                this.solicitudInterface.updateNoAfiliado(solicitud.getNumDocumento(), envioSolicitud);
            }
        } else {
            m.setTexto("Error al realizar pre-radicacion");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        //Agregar Adjuntos
        for (int i = 0; i < solicitud.getArchivoCargados().size(); i++) {
            ESolicitudAdjunto adjunto = new ESolicitudAdjunto();

            String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(solicitud.getArchivoCargados().get(i).getNombreFile());

            Calendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar();

            String newName = (calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "" + calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "" + calendario.get(Calendar.SECOND) + "-" + solicitudInterface.ConsecutivoArchivo() + "." + fileExtension);

            byte[] byteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(solicitud.getArchivoCargados().get(i).getBase64file().getBytes());

            Integer tipoOperacion = solicitud.getArchivoCargados().get(i).getTipoAdjunto();
            adjunto.setIdTicket(envioSolicitud);
            adjunto.setcArchivo(newName);
            adjunto.setcNombreArchivo(solicitud.getArchivoCargados().get(i).getNombreFile());
            adjunto.setIdUserSolicita(userName);
            adjunto.setIdUbicacionArchivo(11);
            adjunto.setBase64(solicitud.getArchivoCargados().get(i).getBase64file());
            adjunto.setExtencion(solicitud.getArchivoCargados().get(i).getExtensionFile());
            adjunto.setBase64Byte(byteArray);

            //String ruta = "/home/oscarrv/formularioPQR/archivoProduccion/";// Produccion
            //String ruta = "/home/oscarrv/PQR9999/archivos/";// Pruebas
            String ruta = "/home/jorgelp/Escritorio/pruebaFile/";//Desarrollo

            try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(ruta + newName)) {
                stream.write(byteArray);
                stream.close();
            }

            this.solicitudInterface.ingresarAdjuntos(adjunto, solicitud.getIdTicket(), adjunto.getIdUserSolicita(), tipoOperacion, 0);

        }

        Boolean envioRadicacion = this.solicitudInterface.radicacion(solicitud);

        if (envioRadicacion) {

            //Obtener los solucionadores
            List<ESolicitudSolucionador> solucionadores = new ArrayList<>();

            if (!"-2".equals(Solicitud.getIdTicket())) {
                //Solucionadores
                for (ServicioInconforme servicioInconforme : solicitud.getServicioInconforme()) {

                    ESolicitudSolucionador solucionador;

                    solucionador = this.solicitudInterface.getSolucionador(Integer.toString(solicitud.getDependenciaId()), Integer.toString(solicitud.getRegionalId()), Integer.toString(servicioInconforme.getValue().getId()));

                    //Validar que el solucionador no exista
                    Boolean exist = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < solucionadores.size(); i++) {
                        if (solucionadores.get(i).getIdUser().equals(solucionador.getIdUser())) {
                            //El usuario ya existe 
                            exist = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!exist) {
                        //Ingresa si el solucionador no existe
                        solucionadores.add(solucionador);
                    }

                }

                int iConsecutivo = 1;
                for (ESolicitudSolucionador solucionadore : solucionadores) {

                    this.solicitudInterface.ingresaNuevaRadicacionHistorico(iConsecutivo, 1, Solicitud.getIdTicket(), solicitud.getTipoComentario().getId(), solucionadore);
                    iConsecutivo++;
                }

                if (solicitud.getServicioInconforme().size() > 1 && solucionadores.size() == iConsecutivo - 1) {
                    String analista = this.solicitudInterface.consultarAnalistaDisponible(2);
                    this.solicitudInterface.ingresaNuevoAuditorCompartida(solicitud.getTipoComentario().getId(), analista, 2, Solicitud.getIdTicket(), iConsecutivo);
                }
            }

            //envio Mail
            /*Mail cuerpoMail = new Mail();
        if (solicitud.getServicioInconforme().size() == 1) {
            cuerpoMail = this.solicitudInterface.datosEnviaMailTicket(solicitud.getIdTicket(), 1);
        } else {
            cuerpoMail = this.solicitudInterface.datosEnviaMailTicket(solicitud.getIdTicket(), 2);
        }

        if (cuerpoMail != null) {
            enviarEmail(cuerpoMail);
        }*/
        }

        m.setTexto("Ticket: " + solicitud.getIdTicket());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (IOException | SQLException pE) {

        String _json = jsonService.toJson(solicitud);

        Message response = new Message(_json);

        throw new PqrException(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, _json, null, pE);
    }
}
```

Esto me ha generado varios inconvenientes ya que se ejecuta la pqr pero no devuelve los datos ya ingresados.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con procedimientos almacenados?

Comment: Tengo diferentes procedimientos almacenados que se van ejecutando segun se va necesitando, mientras se van ejecutando va creando columnas nuevas en la base de datos, pero al generar error necesito que esas columnas de mas sean eliminadas

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar la anotacion

`@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)`

en el metodo, asi:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public ResponseEntity<Message> postSolicitud(@Valid @PathVariable String userName, @Valid @RequestBody Solicitud solicitud) throws Exception {

    Message m = new Message("");
    try {
    ....
```

Comment: Y a los procedimientos almacenados debo hacerles algo o ya con esa anotacion maneja la transacion en todo los procedimientos que ejecute?

Comment: Salvo que en ellos agregues un commit o transaction, no deberias modificarlos